# Apache is not working on MAMP

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp

I have problem viewing php files locally on my mac, it used to work just fine for the past year and suddly apache stopped working for some reason,
I didn't change any thing or any port. 
I'm running El Capitan 10.11.5.

I have tried reinstalling MAMP on my computer and changing 'envvars' to '_envvars' and lots of different terminal commands ,but nothing works.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: is the problem only with apache in mamp?

Comment: yes mysql works just fine

Comment: open the terminal type `sudo apachectl stop`

Comment: I've tried it ,and most of the solutions posted online and here ,but still nothing is working .